# Normal Bake Problem

Tags: modeling, normals, normal-map

I have this wierd problem. My mesh is clean. dont have double faces and my normals are correct and blue. and the problem is just on first picture. The rest of the model is correct!!!
[image]

[image]

---

this is a picture of wired normals in that area of weapon. dont know how to fix that.
[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots sry. its for a project and need director premision.

Comment: share only the part with the problem

Comment: @moonboots sure. I will split this and share it as a blend file for you just tell me where can i share this.
and I posted new picture of my problem. a picture from normals on this post.

Comment: Problem fixed.
It was not mesh but UV problem. My UVs overlapped.

Comment: oh ok, great then....  ;)